# What is a hacksaw called that has a single, straight handle?

Tags: plumbing, saw

I'm in need of a hacksaw like the one on the left in the image link provided. Ideally i need it with six inch or more blade protruding to fit down a pipe. 
[image]
I have seen one in a store but now cant find another

Comment: Do you mean like one of [these](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Stanley-4-1-2-in-Multi-Saw-20-220/100654917?cm_mmc=Shopping%7CG%7CBase%7CD25T%7C25-1_HAND+TOOLS%7CNA%7CPLA%7c71700000034127224%7c58700003933021546%7c92700031755124814&gclid=Cj0KCQjwm6HaBRCbARIsAFDNK-hTxb6NE1MPI4f1U5EaOQpcf5i3K5hDxcmPV1yi7qfn-rMq9HmXwZEaAtzyEALw_wcB&dclid=CKjwyaGhndwCFYIlgQodPEABzg)?

Comment: make a handle by wrapping duct tape around the end of a hacksaw blade

Comment: I just break off a hacksaw blade to the length needed and use vise-grips to hold the blade.

Comment: I have one and I don't know what it's called. +1. And I guess it's a good one because it swings out like a pocket knife.

Answer (score 1):

I believe shopping assistance is off topic for the site, however advise on tools is on topic.

I believe that there is two options that would work for you:

1. A hand holder for a [reciprocating saw blade](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B071VS2JPF):
   [image: reciprocating saw blade]
2. A hand holder for a hacksaw blade, often called a [mini hacksaw](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004Z1W7):
   [image: mini hacksaw]

Comment: The second blade down in the first image I'd call a pull saw.  Cuts when you pull and not push, great for flush mounted small cuts.

Answer (score 1):

I have a few one is called a mini super saw and the other is a "handle it" I googled both and both companies don't show on the net but they are 30 ? + old, you can't put much pressure or the blade will bend. There are several length blades on the market. And both of mine will take all sizes.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Lowe's](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Kobalt-10-in-Cross-Cutting-Hand-Saw/1070275), it is a Cross Cutting Hand Saw. The picture you provided is actually from their website originally. I knew it would be from Lowe's as Kobalt is a store brand.

Stanley Tools refer to it as a [Multi Saw](https://www.stanleytools.com/products/hand-tools/cutting-tools/saws/6-in-fatmax-multi-saw/20-220).